# How to manage events in pyglet as Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, pyglet

I do not understand completely how to use pyglet's event system. What I need to do is to get each event for each frame. In Pygame I can do it in the following way:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 320, 240
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print event
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I accomplish something similar with pyglet, using 'pyglet.window.event.WindowEventLogger()' but I do not how to acces to the information that the WindowEventLogger prints, and it prints the same event more than once.

How could I obtain a pyglet version of the pygame code above?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic example of a working class that dispatches events.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyglet
from time import time, sleep

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, refreshrate):
        super(Window, self).__init__(vsync = False)
        self.frames = 0
        self.framerate = pyglet.text.Label(text='Unknown', font_name='Verdana', font_size=8, x=10, y=10, color=(255,255,255,255))
        self.last = time()
        self.alive = 1
        self.refreshrate = refreshrate

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        if time() - self.last >= 1:
            self.framerate.text = str(self.frames)
            self.frames = 0
            self.last = time()
        else:
            self.frames += 1
        self.framerate.draw()
        self.flip()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            self.render()
            event = self.dispatch_events() # <-- This is the event queue
            sleep(1.0/self.refreshrate)

win = Window(23) # set the fps
win.run()
```

However note that normally I never encounter any events at all in this event queue. Most likely because Pyglet works with function decorators/hooks.

So for instance, if you want to catch keyboard events, you would simply add the following code to this awesome class:

```
def on_key_release(self, symbol, modkey):
        print(symbol, modkey)
```

There's also `on_mouse_motion` etc :)